# Amazon EMR: How to add Amazon EMR MapReduce/Hive/Spark steps with inline shell script in the arguments?

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive, emr, amazon-emr

For example, I have two Hive jobs, where the output of one job is used as a argument/variable in the second job. I can successfully run the following comand on terminal to get my result on the master node of the EMR cluster.

```
[hadoop@ip-10-6-131-223 ~]$ hive -f s3://MyProjectXYZ/bin/GetNewJobDetails_SelectAndOverwrite.hql --hivevar LatestLastUpdated=$(hive -f s3://MyProjectXYZ/bin/GetNewJobDetails_LatestLastUpdated.hql)
```

However, it seems I can not add a Hive step to run `GetNewJobDetails_SelectAndOverwrite.hql` with the Arguments textbox set as `--hivevar LatestLastUpdated=$(hive -f s3://MyProjectXYZ/bin/GetNewJobDetails_LatestLastUpdated.hql)`.
The error is:

> Details : FAILED: ParseException line 7:61 cannot recognize input near
>   '$' '(' 'hive' in expression specification
>
> JAR location : command-runner.jar
>
> Main class : None
>
> Arguments : hive-script --run-hive-script --args -f
>   s3://MyProjectXYZ/bin/GetNewJobDetails_SelectAndOverwrite.hql
>   --hivevar LatestLastUpdated=$(hive -f s3://MyProjectXYZ/bin/GetNewJobDetails_LatestLastUpdated.hql)
>
> Action on failure: Cancel and wait

---

I also tried it with command-runner.jar to run the first hive command. It still does not work:

> NoViableAltException(15@[412:1: atomExpression : ( constant | (
>   intervalExpression )=> intervalExpression | castExpression |
>   extractExpression | floorExpression | caseExpression | whenExpression
>   | ( subQueryExpression )=> ( subQueryExpression ) -> ^(
>   TOK_SUBQUERY_EXPR TOK_SUBQUERY_OP subQueryExpression ) | ( function
>   )=> function | tableOrColumn | expressionsInParenthesis[true] );])    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser$DFA36.specialStateTransition(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:31808)
>     at org.antlr.runtime.DFA.predict(DFA.java:80)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.atomExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:6746)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceFieldExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:6988)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceUnaryPrefixExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7324)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceUnarySuffixExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7380)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceBitwiseXorExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7542)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceStarExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7685)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedencePlusExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7828)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceConcatenateExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:7967)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceAmpersandExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:8177)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceBitwiseOrExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:8314)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceSimilarExpressionPart(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:8943)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceSimilarExpressionMain(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:8816)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceSimilarExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:8697)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceEqualExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:9537)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceNotExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:9703)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceAndExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:9812)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.precedenceOrExpression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:9953)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.expression(HiveParser_IdentifiersParser.java:6686)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.expression(HiveParser.java:42062)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_FromClauseParser.searchCondition(HiveParser_FromClauseParser.java:6446)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser_FromClauseParser.whereClause(HiveParser_FromClauseParser.java:6364)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.whereClause(HiveParser.java:41844)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.atomSelectStatement(HiveParser.java:36755)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.selectStatement(HiveParser.java:36987)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.regularBody(HiveParser.java:36504)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpressionBody(HiveParser.java:35822)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpression(HiveParser.java:35710)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:2284)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1333)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils.parse(ParseUtils.java:77)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils.parse(ParseUtils.java:70)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:468)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1317)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1457)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1227)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:336)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processReader(CliDriver.java:474)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processFile(CliDriver.java:490)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:793)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:234)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:148) FAILED:
>   ParseException line 7:61 cannot recognize input near '$' '(' 'hive' in
>   expression specification

Answer (score 0):

You should execute the two hive commands as 2 different steps on the EMR. Also the arguments should be passed as a list instead of string. You can split your hive command by space (' '), which will return a list and pass this list as argument to the EMR step.

Reference : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/add-steps.html